# How can a project get its own NuGet package instead of using the one the solution uses?

Tags: nuget

I have a C# project, TrendMasterCS2, built in VS 2019 that uses a DLL, TrendData, that relies on System.Data.SQLite.Core, which I get through the NuGet Package Manager.  I opened the TrendMasterCS2 sollutio and uninstalled all NuGet packages from both the executable project and the DLL project.  Then, I added the System.Data.SQLite.Core package to the TrendData project.  I saved all files, and then opened the project file in Notepad.  I saw this:

```
<Reference Include="System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.113.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\TrendMasterCS2\packages\Stub.System.Data.SQLite.Core.NetFramework.1.0.113.3\lib\net45\System.Data.SQLite.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

This looks like a problem to me.  If I ever want to use the TrendData DLL in some other solution, it's going to be carrying around this dependency on the TrendMaster2 folder.  I think I can open TrendData by itself in VS2019 and add the NuGet package there, but is that what I have to do to ensure that TrendData is independent of TrendMasterCS2?

Answer (score 0):

Consider to migrate from `packages.config` to `PackageReference`. (In Visual Studio, right click the `packages.config` and select *Migrate packages.config to PackageReference...*).
One benefit of `PackageReference` is that all packages will be restored to a global package cache directory and the tooling takes care of the actual reference path at compile time.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference for details.

As an alternative you could create a `nuget.config` file and change the `repositoryPath` as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagerestore-section

However I did not get managed to store packages in a project-local path using `nuget.config`.